# IIS refuses client digital certificate with HTTP Failed response

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, ssl, iis, x509certificate

I have an ASP.NET application hosted on IIS version 10.0 on Windows Server 2019 (Amazon EC2).

In this application i turned on the SSL. So, my client makes a GET request to the server and if the user has any Digital Certificate installed on the machine the browser prompt a certificate select window.

When the user chooses a certificate, the request goes to the backend where we validate the certificate. The problem is in some cases there is no response from the server, it refuses the request, the request appear as (failed) in chrome dev tools and our code dont event get to log the error. In this cases we already analised the clients certificates and there is nothing wrong with them.

What could be happening?

Comment: Is this because there is a problem with the certificate selected by the client?

Comment: It is not because the client uses the certificate normally in other websites, including government ones

Comment: For information about "IIS may reject client certificate requests with HTTP 403.7 or 403.16 errors", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/errors-403-7-reject-client-certificate-rquest

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm seeing a very similar issue with Windows Server 2012 R2. One point to note is certificate is accepted on Internet Explorer 11 but not on other browsers